# CMake Assembler error "No such instruction"

Tags: cmake, mingw, gnu-assembler

I am moving an already existing project from Atmel Studio 7.0 with arm-gnu toolchain to CMake with MinGW generator.
I have configured the CXX and C compiler flags as follows:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} "-D__SAMD21G18A__ -DARM_MATH_CM0 -DF_CPU=48000000L -DARDUINO=10808 -DARDUINO_SAMD_ZERO -DARDUINO_ARCH_SAMD -DUSB_VID=0x239A  -DUSB_PID=0x800B -DUSB_PRODUCT="\"Feather M0\"" -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="\"Adafruit\"" -DUSBCON -DDEBUG -DDEBUG_PRINT -DADAFRUIT_FONA_DEBUG -DMQTT_DEBUG -DMQTT_ERROR -ffunction-sections -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -mlong-calls  -Wall -Wa -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -std=gnu99")
```

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} "-x c D__SAMD21G18A__ -DARM_MATH_CM0 -DF_CPU=48000000L -DARDUINO=10808 -DARDUINO_SAMD_ZERO -DARDUINO_ARCH_SAMD -DUSB_VID=0x239A -DUSB_PID=0x800B -DUSB_PRODUCT="\"Feather M0\"" -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="\"Adafruit\"" -DUSBCON -DDEBUG -DDEBUG_PRINT -DADAFRUIT_FONA_DEBUG -DMQTT_DEBUG -DMQTT_ERROR -ffunction-sections -mlong-calls  -Wall -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -Wa-c -std=gnu99")
```

Here is the exact verbose command that generates the error.

```
  :\svn\ATSAMD21_FLowTube_CMAKE\uart2lte\build --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start C:\svn\ATSAMD21_FLowTube_CMAKE\uart2lte\build\CMakeFiles C:\svn\ATSAMD21_FLowTube_CMAKE\uart2lte\build\\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/make/tools/install/bin/make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/svn/ATSAMD21_FLowTube_CMAKE/uart2lte/build'
C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/make/tools/install/bin/make.exe  -f Library\CMakeFiles\Library.dir\build.make Library/CMakeFiles/Library.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/svn/ATSAMD21_FLowTube_CMAKE/uart2lte/build'
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" C:\svn\ATSAMD21_FLowTube_CMAKE\uart2lte C:\svn\ATSAMD21_FLowTube_CMAKE\uart2lte\Library C:\svn\ATSAMD21_FLowTube_CMAKE\uart2lte\build C:\svn\ATSAMD21_FLowTube_CMAKE\uart2lte\build\Library C:\svn\ATSAMD21_FLowTube_CMAKE\uart2lte\build\Library\CMakeFiles\Library.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/svn/ATSAMD21_FLowTube_CMAKE/uart2lte/build'
C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/make/tools/install/bin/make.exe  -f Library\CMakeFiles\Library.dir\build.make Library/CMakeFiles/Library.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/svn/ATSAMD21_FLowTube_CMAKE/uart2lte/build'
[  1%] Building CXX object Library/CMakeFiles/Library.dir/src/Adafruit_SleepyDog/utility/WatchdogSAMD.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\svn\ATSAMD21_FLowTube_CMAKE\uart2lte\build\Library && C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe  @CMakeFiles/Library.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -march=native -mno-avx -D__SAMD21G18A__ -DARM_MATH_CM0 -DF_CPU=48000000L -DARDUINO=10808 -DARDUINO_SAMD_ZERO -DARDUINO_ARCH_SAMD -DUSB_VID=0x239A  -DUSB_PID=0x800B -DUSB_PRODUCT=;"Feather;M0"" -DUSB_MANUFACTURER=""Adafruit"" -DUSBCON -DDEBUG -DDEBUG_PRINT -DADAFRUIT_FONA_DEBUG -DMQTT_DEBUG -DMQTT_ERROR -ffunction-sections -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -mlong-calls  -Wall -Wa -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -std=gnu99" -o CMakeFiles\Library.dir\src\Adafruit_SleepyDog\utility\WatchdogSAMD.cpp.obj -c C:\svn\ATSAMD21_FLowTube_CMAKE\uart2lte\Library\src\Adafruit_SleepyDog\utility\WatchdogSAMD.cpp
C:\Users\rajusa\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAWF2FJ.s: Assembler messages:
C:\Users\rajusa\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAWF2FJ.s:47: Error: number of operands mismatch for `ds'
C:\Users\rajusa\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAWF2FJ.s:53: Error: no such instruction: `isb 0xF'
C:\Users\rajusa\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAWF2FJ.s:527: Error: number of operands mismatch for `ds'
C:\Users\rajusa\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAWF2FJ.s:533: Error: no such instruction: `wfi'
```

Any idea what might be the reason -  in terms of toolchain - assembler ? Is there any way to specify assembler flags in CMake?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could edit your question to include the verbose output of your build so we can see the command generating the errors (e.g. `make -j1 VERBOSE=1` or `ninja -j1 -k1 -v`)?

Comment: Those look like ARM instructions, `isb` being an instruction sync barrier, and I think `wfi` is wait-for-interrupt?  Definitely not x86 (except maybe for `ds` depending on context).  Is there an ARM mingw for ARM Windows?  You should probably include the asm you're trying to assemble as part of your [mcve], at *least* the full lines that the assembler complains about.

Comment: @BrechtSanders Thank you for your comment. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You're using MinGW GCC, which essentially targets Windows.
So I don't believe you can target other platforms..

What you need is a GCC compiler that runs on windows that supports the target platform(s) you need.

For Atmel ARM you can try something like this: http://winavr.sourceforge.net/ (though maybe something more recent may exist).